# Extract enum values from json file

Tags: typescript, stenciljs

Context: Typing the prop of a stencil component, TS Version is 5.3.2

I have a JSON file that look like this

```json
[
  "a",
  "b",
  "c"
]
```

And I would like to create a type that would be `"a" | "b" | "c"`

So far I have tried

```
import data from "data.json"

type Data = typeof data[number]
```

But `Data` type is `string`.

`resolveJsonModule` option is enabled and I've tried without and without `esModuleInterop` option without success.

I would have expected that importing json data would be treated `as const` automatically

Comment: This feature has a lot of upvotes, but still not implemented: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/32063